# IOS Script info.plist doesn't exist

Tags: ios, react-native, voximplant

so i am working on a component for a user, i just need to add the ios build script:

this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -x

yarn add react-native-geolocation-service
yarn add @voximplant/react-native-foreground-service


plutil -insert NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription -string 'Location permission when in use' info.plist

echo "configured iOS settings"
```

So when i start building the app, i get this error:

```
Error: Command failed: /Users/administrator/Code/TestApp2/node_modules/geo-location-jimmy/scripts/install_ios.sh
```

error info:

```
info.plist: file does not exist or is not readable or is not a regular file (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
```

Please can someone help me.